# OBIEE 12C: dashboard prompt auto fill when selection is sql result

Tags: obiee

I wanted to created a dashboard prompt which would automatically fill in with the first available value. This is possible when the selection choices are e.g. all column values. 
What I need is to select my values via sql result but still want to fill in the first available value, but that option is blanked out when choosing sql results.

Is there a way to achieve this, maybe via adapting the xml?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Not sure I am getting what you're on about here. What are you trying to achieve?

Why are you using SQL and not something based on a model? Also "the first available value" is quite vague. Do you mean simply SELECT something FROM somewhere FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS?

Comment: Hi Christian, I've added a picture that explains maybe better what I want to achieve. I want the choice list values to be sql because I need it to be the value of my presentation variable. And then I want this to fill automatically whit this value.

Answer (score 0):

What you have highlighted is ONLY ever active when you have interdependent prompts with constraints. I.e. "Limit values by" set to TRUE

[image]

Comment: And is there no other way to achieve that there will be one filled in? I can't use the default selection because this will only be used when no other value is filled in yet. I have a special scenario where I have a dimension with 3 different roles but the end user can't know of this so when they apply one value to a prompt with role 1 I need this value to be passed through another prompt with the 'same' dimension values but with role 2.

Comment: Cant you capture the first value in a presentation variable and CASE WHEN things based on that?

Comment: Yes but then still this value isn't selected. This value needs to be immediately applied.

Comment: In a second prompt object that's only ever rendered when the first one has been filled out it is...